# Website is accessed through IP address but not domain name?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

I use NGINX and MariaDB on my web server.

I upgraded OS from Debian Squeeze to Debian Wheezy. After this operation I have removed Apache server and Mysql completely. Then, I have installed Nginx and MariaDB.

Now, I access my website through IP address, but I can not access it from domain name. I tried to fix it but I couldn't be successful.

My domain: http://tinyurl.com/lg4kjsg

Domain IP: 37.148.208.85

**etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/virtual;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

**etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain**

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/www/virtual/mydomain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/virtual/mydomain.com/logs/error.log;

location / {
    root   /var/www/virtual/mydomain.coom/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

if (-f $request_filename) { 
  expires 30d; 
  break; 
} 

if (!-e $request_filename) { 
  rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last; 
} 

location ~ .php$ {
   try_files $uri =404; #to prevent zero day exploitsts 
   fastcgi_pass  localhost:9000;  # port where FastCGI processes were spawned 
   fastcgi_index  index.php; 
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/virtual/mydomain.com/htdocs/$fastcgi_script_name;  
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_script_name;
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }

location /phpmyadmin {
       root /usr/share/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               root /usr/share/;
               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
               root /usr/share/;
       }
    }

 }
}
```

**etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
# nginx virtual hosts
37.148.208.85   www.mydomain.com mydomain.com
```

**etc/resolv.conf**

```
search domain.name
nameserver 89.19.21.250
nameserver 89.19.21.251
```

Any solutions/suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your domain ge***.net is not registered in DNS yet.

```
[root@ ~]# ping gencharitaci.net
ping: unknown host gencharitaci.net
[root@ ~]# dig gencharitaci.net

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> gencharitaci.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 15999
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gencharitaci.net.              IN      A

;; Query time: 103 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.80.11#53(10.0.80.11)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov  5 07:21:50 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 34
```

Comment: I got these results '[root@ ~]# ping gencharitaci.net    64 bytes from www.gencharitaci.net (37.148.208.85): icmp_req=76 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms'    '[root@ ~]# dig gencharitaci.net   v; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> gencharitaci.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Who is your provider? Please configure your domain name servers there.
Your ping could work if your domain is in /etc/hosts or /etc/sysconfig/network, so it resolved locally.

Comment: `# whois gencharitaci.net | grep ns
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Name Server: ns1.gencharitaci.net
Name Server: ns2.gencharitaci.net` 

It should not be like this. Name servers for your domain should not be with same domain.

Comment: @YoungS - RE: your answer below - great, so it was DNS problem.

Comment: thank you  @Timothy Ha. After your comment I thought that is a DNS server and checked my old backup files. Your comment helped me a lot.

Comment: @YoungS welcome. I also use nginx and didn't find problems in its configs

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem after editing this file;

**etc/bind/named.conf.local** I found this file on my old backup. I have added these lines  and my problem fixed.

```
// [gencharitaci.net] entry BEGIN
zone "gencharitaci.net" {
  type master;
  file "/var/cache/bind/gencharitaci.net.db";
  allow-transfer { localhost; };
  notify yes;
};
// [gencharitaci.net] entry ENDING

// [gencharitaci.com] entry BEGIN
zone "gencharitaci.com" {
  type master;
  file "/var/cache/bind/gencharitaci.com.db";
  allow-transfer { localhost; };
  notify yes;
};
// [gencharitaci.com] entry ENDING

// [gencharitaci.org] entry BEGIN
zone "gencharitaci.org" {
  type master;
  file "/var/cache/bind/gencharitaci.org.db";
  allow-transfer { localhost; };
  notify yes;
};
// [gencharitaci.org] entry ENDING

// [admin.0050569fc491.gencharitaci.net] entry BEGIN
zone "admin.0050569fc491.gencharitaci.net" {
  type master;
  file "/var/cache/bind/admin.0050569fc491.gencharitaci.net.db";
  allow-transfer { localhost; };
  notify yes;
};
// [admin.0050569fc491.gencharitaci.net] entry ENDING
```